# Does the nnetar function from the forecast library in R allow for backpropagation?

Tags: r, time-series, neural-networks, backpropagation

I think I am confused about how the nnetar function works in R. Does it apply backpropagation to feed-foward network or does it perform another operation involving simulation ?

How does it train on test set data ?

Comment: See https://otexts.com/fpp2/nnetar.html